# dropdown data dissappear after submit spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i have the following JSP class

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="task">
        <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="reference">Reference: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="reference" id="reference"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="reference" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="cause">Cause: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="cause" id="cause"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="cause" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="offense">Offense: </label> </td>
                <td><form:select path="offense.id" items="${offenses}" required="true" itemLabel="offense" itemValue="id"/>  </td>
                <td><form:errors path="offense" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${edit}">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

and the controller methods look like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newTask(ModelMap model) {
    Task task = new Task();
    List<Offense> offenses = offenseService.findAllOffenses();

    model.addAttribute("task", task);
    model.addAttribute("edit", false);
    model.addAttribute("offenses", offenses);
    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/new"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveEmployee(@Valid Task task, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    if (!taskService.isTaskUniqueReference(task.getReference())) {
        FieldError referenceError = new FieldError("Task", "reference", messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.reference", new String[]{String.valueOf(task.getReference())}, Locale.getDefault()));
        result.addError(referenceError);
        return "registration";
    }

    taskService.saveTask(task);

    model.addAttribute("success", "Task " + task.getReference() + " registered successfully");
    return "success";
}
```

the issue is that when i click on submit and an error is triggered, for example duplicated reference field, the error displays correctly to the left of the reference field, but the options from the dropdown menu dissappear, why is the initial modelmap data lost? how can i solve this, i tried re adding the offenses to the model map in case of hasErrors() but didn't solved the problem.

Comment: Every time you return "registration" page, make sure you add all required objects to the model. That should solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Offense> offenses = offenseService.findAllOffenses();
if (!taskService.isTaskUniqueReference(task.getReference())) {
    FieldError referenceError = new FieldError("Task", "reference",
              messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.reference",
              new String[] { String.valueOf(task.getReference()) }, Locale.getDefault()));
    result.addError(referenceError);
    model.addAttribute("offenses", offenses);
    return "registration";
}
```